# Nodemailer not working when i deployed to vercel

Tags: reactjs, nodemailer, remix

I created a form on my webpage and used nodemailer to send email to my gmail acount. the host i'm using is gmail. everything works in development but when i deployed to vercel i don't recieve any email when i use the form. I have tried async and await but it still doesn't work. when i check the function log on vercel there are some instances where i get this error

```
Error: Greeting never received
    at SMTPConnection._formatError (/var/task/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:790:19)
    at SMTPConnection._onError (/var/task/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:776:20)
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:710:22)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:564:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7) {
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  command: 'CONN'
}
```

this is my transporter

```js
  const transporter = NodeMailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    secure: true,
    auth: {
      user: 'fifthtribe05@gmail.com',
      pass: <secretPass>
    }
  });
```

the sendEmail

```js
const mailOptions = {
    from: email,
    to: 'email@gmail.com',
    subject: 'Subject',
    text: `${message} from ${email}`
  };
  
  const sendMessage = async(mailOptions:any)=> { 
    await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error: any, info: { response: string; }){
    console.log("sending");
    console.log(error);

    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
    }
  })};
  await sendMessage(mailOptions);
```

Please i need help or if there is any other alternative

```
Ive read other similar issues on satckoverflow and github. 
1. I've added async and await
2. Ive added secure true
3. it works in development but not in production (vercel)
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, while I was searching for a solution for the same error, I saw this unanswered and i somehow figured it out. All you need to do is to add the port as 465;

```js
{
  port: 465
}
```

Since it's a secured service. With this, It should work.